# Android BackupAgent not backing up / restoring sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, backup

I try to use the BackupAgent to backup my default `sharedpreferences`. This is what I have for `MyBackupAgent`

```
public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

    // The name of the SharedPreferences file
    private final String PREFS = "com.mikebdev.refuelpro_preferences";

    // A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data
    private static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "prefs";


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper sharedPref = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);
        addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, sharedPref);

    }
}
```

When forcing a Backup and restore from ADB, this is what i get in my console:

```
shell@flo:/ $ bmgr backup com.mikebdev.refuelpro
bmgr backup com.mikebdev.refuelpro
shell@flo:/ $ bmgr backup run
bmgr backup run
shell@flo:/ $ bmgr restore com.mikebdev.refuelpro
bmgr restore com.mikebdev.refuelpro
restoreStarting: 2 packages
restoreFinished: 0
done
```

This is what Logcat has to say:

```
09-20 18:47:32.125      525-539/? I/BackupManagerService﹕ Scheduling backup for new app com.mikebdev.refuelpro
09-20 18:47:32.125      525-539/? D/BackupManagerService﹕ Now staging backup of com.mikebdev.refuelpro
09-20 18:47:32.966     525-2458/? D/BackupManagerService﹕ agentConnected pkg=com.mikebdev.refuelpro agent=android.os.BinderProxy@42222800
09-20 18:52:00.336      525-539/? D/BackupManagerService﹕ Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.mikebdev.refuelpro flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }
09-20 18:52:00.336      525-539/? V/BackupManagerService﹕ removePackageParticipantsLocked: uid=10084 #1
09-20 18:52:08.344      525-546/? V/BackupManagerService﹕ restoreAtInstall pkg=com.mikebdev.refuelpro token=f restoreSet=39fa49811177c60b
09-20 18:52:08.354      525-657/? D/BackupManagerService﹕ MSG_RUN_RESTORE observer=null
09-20 18:52:08.935      525-657/? D/BackupManagerService﹕ initiateOneRestore packageName=@pm@
09-20 18:52:08.945      525-657/? V/BackupServiceBinder﹕ doRestore() invoked
09-20 18:52:08.945      525-657/? V/BackupManagerService﹕ No next package, finishing restore
09-20 18:52:08.945      525-657/? I/BackupManagerService﹕ Restore complete.
```

So now I'm wondering what is going on as I have no idea, yet. I don't know why this wouldn't work.

And, how exactly would i back up a little SQLite Database with this service?

thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing jumps out, though full logs would help. Make sure to backup to the local transport and inspect the backup file stored locally on device. Once you have verified that the backup is happening then we can see what's wrong with restore.  Don't forget you still have to call dataChanged() to indicate that you have data to be backed up (after the first backup).

Comment: @HayesHaugen OK to be honest. I read the documentation but I'm having a hard time understanding it all. All I want to to right now is get sharedpreferences backup to work. I'd be very thankful to anyone who can help me with this topic as detailed as possible